# Public Arrays in Excel UDFs

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

32Bit Excel 2015 | 64 Bit Win7

I have a module named LDMod

that looks like this

```
Public MyArray()

Function DoinStuff()
if **IDKWhatTOPutHere** MyArray then Call FillMyArray
DoinStuff = "Done"
End Function

Sub FillMyArray
ReDim MyArray(1 to 10, 1 to 10)
For .....
   ....Blah
Next 
End Sub
```

My Goal is to create and fill a public array once then use it over and over again by the function instead of recreating the array for each cell each time the function is called.

The problem is twofold:

1. I don't know how to check if MyArray has been created yet or not **IDKWhatToPutHere**
2. My Public Array Deceleration isn't allowing me to call the variable array

Comment: No elegant way to see if an array has been dimensioned.  Use a global `mIsFilled ` variable that you set to `true` in `FillMyArray` and use `if  not mIsFilled then Call FillMyArray`

Comment: Depends on your definition of elegance I guess: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/IsArrayAllocated.aspx

Comment: Okay, that'll work -- any ideas on the second part -- for some reason my function is creating a new instance of `MyArray` not using the Public Variable I'm getting the 'Can't compile Module' value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alex, I did decide to just use a dummy variable to hold a boolean

To fix the bigger problem - not being able to target my array I created a sub the dims my array, and then it just gets ReDimed later by another sub - it's not pretty, but at this point function over form.

```
Public LDMCArray()
Public LDMCFillCheck As Boolean

Sub InitializePublicDims()
LDMCFillCheck = False
ReDim LDMCArray(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
End Sub
```

If anyone thinks of a better solution I'd gladly put some more form into this function...